# Why do I have a ton of HID and how can I get rid of them?

Tags: windows-11, device-manager, hid

I have only three USB devices connected to my laptop. A Logitech keyboard, a Razer mouse, and a Toshiba external hard drive. However, I see a LOT of HID when I go to device manager. What is happening?

Is there a way to remove them all at once and install one by one?

[image]

Comment: These are likely happening because different ports are used. Just ignore them. They are not doing any harm. That or just the devices for each port.  I see some here (less) so just ignore them

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The issue is that I cannot possibly know which device to uninstall/disable/update in case I want to.

Comment: HID devices are not ports.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On modern laptops, many of the "creature comfort" things, like lights, fan controllers, extra shortcut buttons (think volume control, backlight control, that sort of thing) are also HID devices. Some wifi cards expose their RFKILL switch as a HID device.

Most of them will be internal to the laptop and or hardware in the laptop.

I don't understand the issue however. You should not uninstall any of these. Nor should you need to expressly update any of these. And if you need to, using the connection tree view will allow you to find things like third party keyboards/mice and such, so locating the correct device should be quite easy.